# Spring batch Partitioning execute slave step in other pods in Kubernetes

Tags: java, kubernetes, spring-batch

I've read the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/scalability.html#partitioning) about partitioning on spring batch. They say that it is possible to execute a step remotely.
It's possible to create pods that executes the partitioned slave step?

If yes someone knows how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a remote partitioning setup, workers are listeners on a queue in which messages coming from the manager are of type `StepExecutionRequest`. So you can package workers as a regular message listening app (a long running process) waiting for step execution requests on a given queue.

The `StepExecutionRequestHandler` provided by Spring Batch and that is used on the worker side is able to handle requests for different jobs, so workers can be reused for different jobs.

So the way to deploy workers of a partitioned Spring Batch job in kubernetes would be the same way you would use to deploy a regular message consumer app.

Comment: I'm not understanding sorry. In this [doc](https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/feature-guides/batch/partitioning/) for example they are starting another instance of the batch and playing with profiles. If I put the workers listening on a queue how the step will look like? And how the workers can tell if they have finished to the master step if they are regular consumers on a queue? I can edit the question if needed

Comment: I think [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-task/tree/main/spring-cloud-task-samples/partitioned-batch-job) there is a solution. They are launching docker images and deploying it on kubernetes.

Comment: Here is an example https://stackoverflow.com/a/75285942/5019386 that explains the basic structure of workers. This can be packaged as a Spring Boot  app (with a JMS/RabbitMQ/Kafka listener) as a long running process. It is up to you to package it in a docker container and deploy it to Kubernetes. The link you referred to is an example of a `StepExecutionRequestHandler` from the SCT project which follows the same approach.

Comment: In the example you linked how you configure the master to write on a queue? and how the master step will look like? I cannot figure out this.

Comment: You can find a complete sample here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/tree/main/spring-batch-samples/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/samples/partitioning/remote/polling